# Can not display received buffer using socket

Tags: android, c++, linux, sockets, g++

I have implemented a c++ server runs in linux to receive a string from an Android client. The connection established successfully and the string received successfully as well (I know that from the number of bytes received!), however, I can't display the message in one go, I need to access the Char array to display each character.
The data been sent on Android using this line :

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(StringToSent);
```

This is the code of the server below :

```
char receivedBuff[1025];    
Connection = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
                cout << "Connection accepted \n";

                numOfBytes = read(Connection,receivedBuff,sizeof(receivedBuff));
                  if (numb < 0) 
                       printf("ERROR reading from socket");
                  printf("%s\n",receivedBuff);
```

When I try to display the received buffer using the line below, I got nothing :

```
cout << receivedBuff << Lendl;
```

However, I can get it a char by char like the line below, but it is messy!

```
cout << receivedBuff [0] << receivedBuff[1]  << receivedBuff[2] << endl;
```

I have tried to cast the char Array to string and it does not work. Any suggestions?

*********** THE LAST UPDATE WITH SOLUTION *********** 
Android side :

```
PrintStream ps = null;
                ps = new PrintStream(socketw.getOutputStream());
                ps.println(MessageToSent +'\0');
```

Server side :

```
 numOfBytes = read(Connection,receivedBuff,sizeof(receivedBuff));
              if (numb < 0) 
                   printf("ERROR reading from socket");
              printf("%s done %d",receivedBuff, numOfBytes);
```

*********** THE LAST UPDATE WITH SOLUTION ***********

Comment: Show exactly the contents of StringToSend and tell us the value of numOfBytes please.

Comment: Add receivedBuff[numOfBytes]=0;

Comment: StringToSent = "ABCD"
numOfBytes= 6
There are 2 bytes added on each message I sent I don't know why, if StringToSent = "AB" then numOfBytes will be 4.

Comment: 'There are 2 bytes added on each message'. And you will not tell where? In front or at end?

Comment: @greenapps Thank you for your concern, I have replaced the dataOutputStream with PrintStream.println on android and now it does not add any extra bytes. On the server sides it fills the empty spaces with zeros like this: thank you green apps
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 done 21 bytes

Comment: I have append the SentMessage in Android with '\0' and it solved the problem, here is the last output:
Connection accepted 
thank you greenapps done 20 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataOutputStream.writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) writes a 16bit length followed by that number of UTF-8-like bytes.

`printf` prints a NUL terminated C string.

The two are not compatible. Specifically, for a string < 256 bytes, the first byte written by `writeUTF` is NUL, thereby resulting in a C-string of length 0, like you're seeing.

It is up to you to decide on a common protocol and implement it on both the client side and the server side. A simple example is to write strings as UTF-8 encoded data terminated by a line feed: you can do this with [PrintStream.println](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) in Java and [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) in C++.

Comment: Thank you, do you know any compatible functions ?

Comment: @MohammedAl-sadi Yes, see update. If you decide on a line based protocol, you can easily find examples for how to read or write lines to sockets in both languages.